# Re-deploying Delphi Android App to device deletes saved data file

Tags: android, delphi

I have an Android App that loads a csv file on the `OnActivate` event and saves the (edited) file on the `OnClose` event.  This all works perfectly well.  However if I modify my app and redeploy to my target device, the text file is deleted and all data is lost.  Is there a way to stop this behavior.  It is worth noting that if I redeploy the app from Delphi whilst the app is active on the target device, the data / text file is not deleted.

To Load the file I use...

```
MyList.LoadFromFile(System.ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath +
      System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'datalist.csv');
```

To save the file I use ...

```
MyText.SaveToFile(System.ioutils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath +
      System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'datalist.csv');
```

I am assuming that the file is saved in the applications default folder on the target device.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You could also use use TPath.Combine to merge documentspath and 'datalist.csv'

Comment: Do you have -cleaninstall as a parameter value in run->parameters? Is your file listed as "overwite always" in the deployment manager? Do you have System.StartupCopy linked in?

Comment: How do you redeploy when not from Delphi? Do you perform uninstall/install? In that case all files would be lost.

Comment: Hi Dalija - I redeploy from Delphi and also I email  the apk file  and install from my downloads folder on the target device. Either way, the outcome is the same.  If the app is inactive on the target device, the file is deleted, if the app is active it is not deleted.  I am currently looking into the deployment manager supplied by nolaspeaker.  Maybe I need to save the file in some other place like local storage documents - but I am not sure how to do that at the moment.

Comment: (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)

Comment: Thank you all for your help - I seem to have the Deployment manager working correctly now and the remote path for the file now set to `.\assets\internal` and the file set to `overwrite never`  This seems to have done the trick.